# How ErrorUtils work with android for uncaught exception in React Native on debug and production mode?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to catch uncaught exception of android react native app. For this some blogs suggesting to use following code:

```
 ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(error => {
    sentry.capture(error);
    NativeModules.BridgeReloader.reload()
  });
```

But I don't know the complete mechanism to implement this. Can any one let me know how do I implement code for such requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution, We should use ErrorUtils handler to detect run time exception. For this we have to add

```
if (ErrorUtils._globalHandler) {
            instance.defaultHandler = ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler && ErrorUtils.getGlobalHandler() || ErrorUtils._globalHandler;
            ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler(this.wrapGlobalHandler);  //feed errors directly to our wrapGlobalHandler function
        }
```

and in your wrapGlobalHandler method

```
async wrapGlobalHandler(error, isFatal) {

      //* Report error here

      setTimeout (() => {
        this.defaultHandler(error, isFatal);  //after you're finished, call the defaultHandler so that react-native also gets the error
        if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
          NodeModule.reload()
        }
      }, 1000);
}
```